# How to get Top-50 query with Parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I don't know How to get Top-50 query with Parse.com,
so Can you tell me that?

This code is get all query,but I'd like to get top-50 query.
But I don't how to get Top-50 or latest-50 query.

```
func loadData() {

    comments.removeAllObjects()
    var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Comment")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.limit = 1000
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error != nil){
            //error
        }


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            // Task
            for object in objects {

                if object["commentId"] as? String == nil {
                self.comments.addObject(object)
                    if  self.comments.count == 50 {
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                // UI
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.stopIndicator()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Language is Swift.

Please answer me.

Comment: @picot -- in parse if you are not set the limit it default given  The first 100 objects are available in objects, here no need to check the limit

Comment: if your assistance please refer this [link](https://parse.com/questions/fetch-all-data-in-a-table-using-pfquery)

Comment: Thanks for your comment,but I know that.I'd like to know how to get only latest-50 query.

Comment: u get the data on **createdAt** method , sort the date u get order wise da

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query for the latest 50 records on Parse you need to limit the query for 50 objects (Default limit is 100).

```
func loadData() {

    self.comments.removeAllObjects()
    var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Comment")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.limit = 50 //<--- change this line
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
          if (error != nil){
              //error
          }

          // Add the received objects to your array
          self.comments.addObjectsFromArray(objects)

          // No need to perform any task in background thread, so update the UI
          self.tableView.reloadData()
          self.stopIndicator()
    }
}
```